# React - Single page Or Multiple pages

Tags: reactjs

Our web app has about 60+ pages developed by JSP,
we want to rewrite it by react.

Until now ,we replace one JSP(HomePage) by react,
but what about the rest?

What's the best practice? 
demos to references?

Answer (score 0):

The question is too wide.

If you want to create [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), look at [this tutorial](https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm) for starting point.